# Objective-c Shinobi Grids Update to 2.8

Tags: ios, objective-c, shinobi

I am using Shinobi Grids 1.1 and I am looking to upgrade to 2.8. I cant seem to find any documentation on this online, does anyone know of any documentations online I can look to point me in the right direction? Please and thank you.

Comment: Do you review the [shinobicontrols.com](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobitoolkit) website?

Comment: yes, I dont see anything on how to upgrade or update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I am a developer at ShinobiControls.

If you're a customer, you can download version 2.8.0 of ShinobiGrids from our customer portal. Otherwise, you can download a trial version available on our main site [HERE](http://www.shinobicontrols.com).

Once downloaded remove the old framework from your project and drag and drop the new one in. You may get warnings and possibly some compile errors seen as you are updating from such an old version. However, any warnings you get should describe an alternative implementation.

If you get any compiling errors or warnings that aren't clear, just email us at info@shinobicontrols.com. A member of our team will get back to you as soon as they can.